Creating plugins with flutter for windows/linux
Is it possible to create plugins in Flutter similar to those that show the processor temperature in the Windows/Linux navigation bar?

Flutter uses .NET/win32 on Windows and GTK on Linux to host its UI, so if those libraries can be used to make navigation bar widgets (which I don't know off hand), then in theory you can use Flutter to power them. But if your question is if you can do this easily or in a straightforward way, I suspect the answer is no.

If I understood your question, Yes, Flutter can do it.
But that are plugins or softwares that is running in System Trail in TaskBar?
Maybe you are searching it:
https://github.com/leanflutter/tray_manager
You can create a New Project and in Project Type select to Plugin/Package/Module.
After select in Plataform your target, Windows.

You can find more here
https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages
